# Conversão de float em string - como apresentar duas ou mais casas decimais?

Tags: java, string, float

Tenho o código abaixo, que retorna valores do tipo `float`. Como posso fazer com que o resultado seja apresentado com duas ou mais casas decimais?

```
private void btnDividirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        float n1 = Float.parseFloat(txtNumerador.getText());
        float n2 = Float.parseFloat(txtDenominador.getText());

        float divisao = n1 / n2;
        float resto = n1 % n2;

        rsDivisao.setText(Float.toString(divisao));
        rsResto.setText(Float.toString(resto));
```

Comment: Mas é suposto apresentar com duas casas decimais mesmo que sejam zeros ?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar este método:

```
public BigDecimal toBigDecimal(float number) {
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(Float.toString(number)); // converte para BigDecimal
    bd.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP); // arredonda para 2 casa decimais o valor
    return bd;
}
```

Se quiser alterar o número de casas decimais desejado, basta passar também por parâmetro o valor no lugar do `2`.

Então, para usá-lo:

```
rsDivisao.setText(toBigDecimal(divisao).toString());
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @RogerioSantos por nada. Se a resposta o ajudou, poderia marcar a solução como correta? Obrigado

Comment: o método funcionou bem, porém a chamada apresenta erro (
tipos incompatíveis: BigDecimal não pode ser convertido em String).

Comment: Consegui solucionar da seguinte forma: 
        
        rsDivisao.setText(String.format("%.2f", divisao));
        rsResto.setText(String.format("%.2f", resto));

Comment: @RogerioSantos, chame o método `toString()` do BigDecimal para funcionar. Um alerta: veja se você realmente precisa usar `float` para seu problema. Se pretende trabalhar com precisão em casas decimais, o `BigDecimal` do Java é mais recomendado, pois com float (ou double) você logo perceberá problemas na [precisão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320209/javawhy-should-we-use-bigdecimal-instead-of-double-in-the-real-world).